# Retrieve JPQL Query as DTO in Spring boot application

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpql

What I am basically trying to do is to run a query and put the result within the object of the class `Account`. What is very important to emphasize is that the query performs a JOIN between 2 tables THAT ARE NOT MAPPED as `@Entity`. So how can I do that?

This is my **FooRepository.java** class

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  Foo findById(Long id);

@Query(value = "SELECT Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME," +
          "Q2.GROUP_NAME  " +
          "FROM USERS_DEV Q1\n" +
          "JOIN USERS_GROUPS Q2 ON Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME = Q2.ACCOUNT_NAME\n" +
          "WHERE LOWER(Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME) = 'john.pit'", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Account> getAllAccounts();
```

So how can I change my query to get the desired result?

And here is my **Account.java** class

```
public class Account {

    String samAccountName;
    String groupName;

    public Account(String accountName, String groupName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `nativeQuery` whenever possible. That said, this _should_ work if you map the property names appropriately (constant-case is no longer the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `@NamedNativeQuery` with `@SqlResultSetMapping` in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name = "findAllAccounts",
  query = 
     "SELECT " +
     "  Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME AS accountName, " +
     "  Q2.GROUP_NAME AS groupName " +
     "FROM USERS_DEV Q1 " +
     "JOIN USERS_GROUPS Q2 ON Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME = Q2.ACCOUNT_NAME " + 
     "WHERE LOWER(Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME) = 'john.pit'",
  resultSetMapping = "findAllAccountsMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
   name = "findAllAccountsMapping",
   classes = @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = Account.class,
      columns = {
         @ColumnResult(name="accountName"),
         @ColumnResult(name="groupName"),
      }
   )
)
public class Foo {
   // ...
}
```

and `FooRepository`:

```java
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @Query(name = "findAllAccounts", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Account> getAllAccounts();
}
```

See hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-scalar-named-queries) for additional details.

Comment: Could not extract result set Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: still getting `FROM keyword not found where expected` but when I copy-paste the query in sql developer, it works perfectly. I really don`t understand :(

Comment: @MariusPop Try to use mapping from my updated answer. If it will not help please enable `hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql` and `hibernate.use_sql_comments` and look what exactly query executed.

Comment: the problem was the spacing. I didnt` know that sql glues everything so some of the words were glued also

Comment: Ok, yes, I have seen your question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityManager` and `ResultTransformer`:

```java
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME," +
    "Q2.GROUP_NAME  " +
    "FROM USERS_DEV Q1 " +
    "JOIN USERS_GROUPS Q2 ON Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME = Q2.ACCOUNT_NAME " +
    "WHERE LOWER(Q1.ACCOUNT_NAME) = 'john.pit'"
)
            .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
            .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {
                @Override
                public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                    return new Account(
                        (String) tuple[0],
                        (String) tuple[1]
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public List transformList(List collection) {
                    return collection;
                }

            })
            .getResultList();
```

A cast might be needed.

Comment: I did as you said so now I`m getting this one : InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @MariusPop yes, that's my mistake, I thought it's jpql. For native there should be other solution, let me edit my answer

Comment: @MariusPop try now. Don't worry about the deprecation of `ResultTransformer` it will not be removed until there is a decent replacement

Comment: i`m not quite familiar to entityManager. Where more precisely should I paste this code ? Still in the repository class ? Should I create an instance of EntityManager?

Comment: @MariusPop You can create a separate class, I suggest `CustomFooRepository`, there you can create a method that returns `List<Account>` and paste the code. `EntityManager` can be injected with `@Autowired`

Comment: NativeQuery.class is not found so I added the following dependency but after that it doesnt find setResultTransformer anymore. Can you please tell me what version of NativeQuery class did you use ? I used this one <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.gasparbarancelli</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-native-query</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.25</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @MariusPop it's `org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery`, do you have hibernate on classpath?

Comment: I do not. I had only spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: @MariusPop I think it should depend on hibernate. What happend when you use `import org.hibernate.query.Query` and `Query` instead of `NativeQuery`?

Comment: If i do so, it doesnt find setResultTransformer method anymore. If I add hibernate dependecy to the classpath then I`m getting 
ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222594/discussion-between-andronicus-and-marius-pop).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but i remember you can do the follow (with HQL):

```java
@Query("select new Account(u.name, g.groupName) " +
          "from User as u" +
          "join u.group as g" +
          "where LOWER(u.name) = 'john.pit'")
```

Syntax could be wrong, but I'm sure you can use DTO constructor in select statement if you use HQL.

Hope this will helps you :D

Comment: this works only if the tables are mapped as entities